# unknown MSBuild failure on osx

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, xamarin.ios, mvvm-light, build-error

I have been working on a xamarin ios application with MVVMlight framework.

It was working without any problem but suddenly I am getting the following error

```
Unknown MSBuild failure.Please try the building the project again
```

Herewith I have attached the screenshot of build log

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I click the error it leads to the .csproj file

[image]

I have verified the the xml is syntactically right no presence of any special character that can cause any xml problem

So far I have tried clean & build,removing the obj and bin manually,restarting the xamarin.But nothing works so far.

The problem is not seen in Visual studio though

Any suggestions to solve the problem is welcome

Comment: Have you update anything regarding xam studio or so on yiur mac?

Comment: Yes,I have updated it,I guess.I am using version 6.2

Comment: i think that could be the issue for breaking. Needs to check your logs or you can check the release notes here (if you haven't already) https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/studio/xamarin.studio_6.2/xamarin.studio_6.2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a space in one of the directory name in the path.

I replaced the space with %20 for directory name on Finder and it started working.